# duplicate id values generating in JPA entity when copy data from another table and continue

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I have an entity with autogenerated id value and I am using MySQL DB

**entity definition**

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

private long id;

**table column definition in MYSQL**

id bigint not null auto_increment

And I had to copy data to the table from external and I want to continue generating entities and save them, But seems in JPA side it generates id values which already have in the DB (which are copied from externally)

Is there any way to tell JPA, generate next id from whatever in MySQL table?

And when I use both autogenerating from JPA side and auto-increment column in DB side, how internally it works, which side gets the priority?

Answer (score 0):

GenerationType.IDENTITY is not the best way of use, due to a lack of performance it involves. The way it work is that it relies on an auto-incremented database column and lets the database generate a new value with each insert operation, so there would be a sequence in DB which generates the values.

But here comes the problem: if you use Hibernate, it requires a primary key value for each managed entity, so it has to perform the insert statement immediately to be able to work. This avoid the use of JDBC batching optimization.

> And when I use both autogenerating from JPA side and auto-increment
> column in DB side, how internally it works, which side gets the
> priority?

The @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE) indicates the provider to use a table to get the IDs when inserting new entities into the database.

When using Hibernate as provider, you will find a table called hibernate_sequences with two columns: entity name and max identity already assigned to this entity.

Hope this helps.